Should I include my documentaries under publications in my CV
I have been published in a journal and produced multiple documentaries, should I include the documentaries under publications. Unlike the journal publications, the documentaries were not peer-reviewed as no such process exists.

CVs are produced for a purpose, usually for getting a job. If you apply for an academic position or a research position or a graduate program, you want to highlight your scientific creativity by showing your publications. In this case, You can put your documentaries under publications, but within their own group, so that it is clear that they are not peer-reviewed at a first glance.
If you want to craft your CV for getting a job that combines your film making skills with your scientific prowess, you could also do this, but you might make a stronger impression if you list them in their own category and your academic pubs in a different one.
Whatever you do:

Make it easy to understand. Many CVs get sorted out within seconds.
Do not appear to deceive. You do not want a reaction that says: "Wait a minute, this is not an academic publication, this is a youtube video".

Writing CVs is a difficult art, that starts out with identifying, selecting, and ordering the relevant information. Often, universities offer workshops or help. Avail yourself of these types of offers. Somebody with experience will be able to give you great feedback on whatever you can come up with.

Sadly, after years of seeing the results of university workshops, I can only say that perhaps the career centers are better than nothing but it isn’t by much. My kids agree with me.

No. They are documentaries, not publications.
Put them in their own section, which could be called something like Documentaries, TV productions, YouTube productions, or Public outreach.
